# Retrieve class name from within static method in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to retrieve the class name from within a static method. It works from an ordinary method but not from within a static method

```
 class MyNode{
    constructor(){
        var classname=this.constructor.toString().split ('(' || /s+/)[0].split (' ' || /s+/)[1];
        console.log(classname);
    }
    static a_static_method(){
        var classname=this.constructor.toString().split ('(' || /s+/)[0].split (' ' || /s+/)[1];
        console.log(classname);
    }
}
var obj=new MyNode(); // THIS WORKS, prints "MyNode" 
MyNode.a_static_method(); // THIS DOESN'T, prints "Function"
```

I forgot to tell: it should work for the derived classes of MyNode.

Comment: FYI: in the non static method, you can use `this.constructor.name` instead of that long regexp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please check following solution:

```
class MyNode{
    constructor(){
        var classname=this.constructor.toString().split ('(' || /s+/)[0].split (' ' || /s+/)[1];
        console.log(classname);
    }
    static a_static_method(){
        var classname = this.toString().split ('(' || /s+/)[0].split (' ' || /s+/)[1];
        console.log(classname);
    }
}
```

In derived class you will get the name of that class, not `MyNode`

Comment: This answer is quite old, please see the answer below. You can use `this.name` now, apparently.

Answer (score 29):

Now you can just use `this.name`

Comment: It feels so strange referencing this from a static context, but it works.

Comment: The official TS 1.8 documentation states (8.2.1): "Within static member functions and static member accessors, the type of this is the constructor function type."

Answer (score 4):

Previous answers will fail in certain cases

```js
class cl_s2{
 constructor(){
    }

static a_static_method(){
        var classname = this.toString().split ('(' || /s+/)[0].split (' ' || /s+/)[1];
        console.log(classname);
    }

static get is() {
    return this.toString().replace(new
    RegExp('^class(?: |\n|\r)+([^\s\n\r{]+)[\s\n\r{](?:\s|\n|\r|.)+', 'i'), '$1').trim();
  }

static get className() {
        let classNameRegEx = /(?:\S+\s+){1}([a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*)/;
        return classNameRegEx.exec( this.toString() )[1];
    }
}

//Will fail in chrome because toString will return " class cl_s2{ ...", so there will be no "("
cl_s2.a_static_method();

//Will fail in browser which will display "function cl_s2(){" instead
// and in classes with underscore in name
console.log(cl_s2.is);

//this will work as long as you do not use unicode chars in classnames
console.log(cl_s2.className);
```

Answer (score 0):

Improved method.

How to get class name in a static method

Useful for polymer 2.0 elements

The following code :

```
class G {
  static get is() {
    return this.toString().replace(new
    RegExp('^class(?: |\n|\r)+([^\s\n\r{]+)[\s\n\r{](?:\s|\n|\r|.)+', 'i'), '$1').trim();
  }
}; 

G.is
```

Gives you :

```
"G"
```